# Reading binary data 40 bits at a time

Tags: c

I'm trying to access binary data 10 bits at a time. I figured the best way would be to read 40 bits into at unsigned long long and then use bit masking to access the desired data. My efforts seem to read 64 bits and I was wondering if someone could point out where I'm going wrong. Thanks.

```
FILE * pFile;
long lSize;
unsigned long long * buffer;
size_t result;

pFile = fopen ( "test.bin" , "rb" );
if (pFile==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}

fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
lSize = (ftell (pFile))/5;
rewind (pFile);

buffer = (unsigned long long*) malloc (sizeof(unsigned long long)*lSize);
if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}

result = fread (buffer,5,lSize,pFile);
if (result != lSize) {fputs ("Reading error",stderr); exit (3);}
```

When I output buffer[0] I'm getting:

```
0100110111001110101110001110000111011111110001100011100110111011
```

but I thought I would get something like:

```
0000000000000000000000001110000111011111110001100011100110111011
```

Comment: And what is the actual contents of the file test.bin? Open it in some hex editor, like HxD (assuming you work in Windows).

Comment: Initialize the buffer with zeros - use `calloc` for example.

Comment: @Dialecticus I just downloaded a hex editor and checked and the contents do not match. There 1011101100111001110001101101111100111001110001101101111111100001

Comment: "When I output buffer[0] ..." doesn't seem using a standard C library function. How did you get that output?

Comment: @RadLexus I used cout.

Comment: @pSoLT I tried to use calloc but but the output is still not matching my expectations. This is my first time using it so perhaps I'm doing something wrong. Here's what I used. buffer = (unsigned long long*) calloc (lSize,sizeof(unsigned long long));

Comment: Casting malloc is bad https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjz6-bEh8XRAhVrLMAKHQqBAJQQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F605845%2Fdo-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc&usg=AFQjCNFdU-kCJmTrKEINqV3P50zb3ce7VA&sig2=reC4JX-Zl1uoa5dN-XeJ5g

Comment: Hmmm? Please show that code then, as I don't think `cout` is C. The reason for my insistence is because it is plausible you *think* your code is not working, because of the unexpected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most current operating systems do not allow bit access to files. Files are read via system calls (`read()`...) or Standard library functions (`getc()`, `fread()`...) on a byte by byte basis.

In order to manipulate the contents as bits, you need to know how these bits are stored (packed) into the file bytes.

Sometimes bits are packed into the low order bits first, sometimes into the high order bits first, sometimes this packing in done on a word basis, which adds an extra layer of complexity as words can be stored in least significant byte first (aka little endian format) or in most significant byte first (aka big endian format).

A common approach is to keep a one byte buffer along with a count of unread bits:

```
typedef struct bitreader {
    FILE *stream;
    int bits;
    unsigned char buffer;
} bitreader;

bitreader *bitopen(const char *filename) {
    bitreader *bp = calloc(sizeof(*bp));
    if (bp) {
        bp->stream = fopen(filename, "rb");  // open in binary mode
        if (bp->stream == NULL) {
            free(bp);
            bp = NULL;
        }
    }
    return bp;
}

void bitclose(bitreader *bp) {
    fclose(bp->stream);
    free(bp);
}

/* simplistic method to read bits packed with most significant bit first */
long long int bitread(bitreader *bp, int count) {
    long long int val = 0;
    while (count > 0) {
        if (bp->bits == 0) {
            int c = getc(bp->stream);
            if (c == EOF)
                return EOF;
            bp->buffer = c;
            bp->bits = 8;
        }
        val <<= 1;
        val |= (bp->buffer >> 7) & 1;
        bp->buffer <<= 1;
        bp->bits--;
        count--;
    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer it's very thorough.